Multiple js file import not working with IJSObjectReference
Importing multiple .js modules for JsInterop in a Blazor component as follows:
[Inject]
public IJSRuntime JS { get; set; }

public IJSObjectReference? _jsModule;

protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
{
 if(firstRender) {
  _jsModule = await JS.InvokeAsync<IJSObjectReference>(
  "import", 
  new string[] {
    "./lib1.js",
    "./lib2.js"
   }
  );
 }
}

this result in loading only the first js file (lib1.js).
Any ideas?
